# Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply.. pyodbc

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am trying to get data using pyodbc from ms sql server. I am getting below error :

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Some part of your SQL statement is nested too
>   deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries. (191)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)')

Code is below :

```
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=Morphemes;')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        Func = list()
        sql_VerbDecl = "SELECT (stem_.kök + conj_.suffix) as tokenn  FROM TBL_Stem as stem_ INNER JOIN TBL_VerbDecl  as conj_ on  conj_.node =  stem_.node;"
        cursor.execute(sql_VerbDecl)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

The problem was an unicode problem. When I changed stem_.kök to stem_.kok,the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any "AS blah". Try the exact same code except have sql_VerbDecl = "SELECT 1;" and see if you get the same error. Try this, it might not be the exact syntax but you should get the idea `SELECT "TBL_Stem.kök", "TBL_VerbDecl.suffix" FROM "TBL_Stem" INNER JOIN "TBL_VerbDecl" ON "TBL_Stem".node = "TBL_VerbDecl".node;` Refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp on how to INNER JOIN. Also, anytime where your table name or table column includes capitalization, you need to surround it in "" or SQL won't know it's capitalized.